# textView updates do not show

Tags: android

Ok - preface with I am new to android and new to java as well.  But I did code in a previous lifetime.....

I am working on an application and now trying to pull some methods out and place into a utility class.  In particular, I have a method which updates text views that I wanted to move out of an activity.

When in the activity, I had two versions of the method the only difference being that one would accept a view in the parameter list (I used this to populate some fields in a custom dialog). They all worked fine.

Once placed in the external utility package/class, the method no longer works - no errors, and it appears to have all it needs - I've done some logging and the view claims to be visible and the textview ids appear to be correct.   Yet nothing changes on the screen.

I'm guessing this is something completely obvious and stupid but I can't seem to sort it out.

```
package xxx.xxx.Utility;

(some imports)

public class Utility {
    public static void updateTextView(int id, String opt_data, View v) {
        String TAG = "updateTextView: ";
        if (v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) Log.i(TAG," visible");
        TextView tvTarget = (TextView) v.findViewById(id);
        if (tvTarget == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error: updateTextView target is null");
        }
        if (opt_data != null) {
            if (tvTarget != null) {
                tvTarget.setText(opt_data);               
            }
        } else {
            if (tvTarget != null) {
                tvTarget.setText(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT w/ Additional Info:

In the inital description I mentioned that this method was also being used to populate some fields of a pop-up dialog with data.  In fact, I can request any number of dialogs in that manner and they all display properly and with the correct (and different) data.   So it seems to fail only when trying to update the tv data of the main activity (the initial) view.

Comment: is the external package in the src directory as well? or did you created a library project or a jar? for you utility package/class?

Comment: Post your implementation please.. Just a general reminder: You cannot make changes to views from other threads. Only from the UI thread that created them.

Comment: If you only want to update TextViews and at the same time make debugging a little easier, change the function to actually take a TextView as an argument and do all lookups before calling the function. If things broke while refactoring, try to minimize the changes to find the error.

Comment: @Peshal Yes, the package is in source directory (I am using IDEA)

Comment: @Igor unless I have misunderstood, this is all running on the same thread.  The only difference is the method is now inside a utility package/class instead of a method in the main activity

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing this is something completely obvious and stupid but I
>   can't seem to sort it out.

It helps to get the root(?) parent (?) view properly.  IE,

currentView = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();

and now all is well.